# how to design a trade calculator by python elegantly?

Tags: python, pandas, algorithm, trading

assume i have a stock price sequence and a buy/sell signal sequence.

I want to calculate the profit and loss for each signal.

for example:

```
price = [100, 99, 98, 99, 101, 102]
signal= [1,   -1,  1,  1,  -1,   0]  # 1 -> buy 1, -1 -> sell 1
```

these two sequence means: i buy the stock in time 1(bc the first element of signal is 1), sell it in time2, ....

i need a function to return the profit or loss for each signal, the function looks like:

```
def calculate(price, signal):
  pnl = []
  # wait to be written
  return pnl
```

here is the expected return:

```
[0, -1, ......]
```

for the first element of signal, that's a buy signal, which means i buy in time1, it produce no profit or loss, because i dont close the trade(close means buy then sell, or vice verse), i just buy one(open the trade). so the first element of pnl(the expected return array) should be 0, or nan.

when the second signal comes, that's a sell, so, it causes close trade(this sell, last buy), we can calculate the pnl=sell price(99) - buy price(100) = -1, which means i loss one unit, so the second element is -1, ....

the tough part of the problem is:

i may open several times, then close one by one or close all.

for example:

```
price = [100, 99, 98, 99, 101, 102]
signal= [1,   1,  -1,  -1,  -1,   0]  # 1 -> buy 1, -1 -> sell 1
```

i buy 100 at time1, buy 99 at time2, sell one at 98.

the expected result of sell should be

```
[0, 0, -1.5, -0.5, ....]
```

98(this sell price) - 99.5(average price of buy) = -1.5
99 - 99.5 = -0.5

i know this can be implemented using loop in python, since the purpose is so clear.

but i want to ask you for help about is there is any elegant and fast method can do this(like python rolling method or other)?

i do care about the algorithm performance, because i need to use it in a very huge dataset.

Comment: Are you going to take into consideration taxes, now or in the future, or is this a purely theoretical exercise?

Comment: Your total profit will be `sum(p*s for p,s in zip(price, signal))`. I hope this is "elegant" enough for you. But I should say I did not understand most of your explanations; in particular I don't understand the logic behind your `-1.5` calculation; so I won't comment about that.

Comment: Note that if your "very huge dataset" is a numpy array, then you should probably use numpy functions instead. If it's a pandas dataset, then you should probably use pandas functions instead. If it's a spark dataset, then you should probably use pyspark functions instead.

Comment: @PaulBrennan in the future, i will, but for now, it's okay to ignore it

Comment: @Stef i think i may not explain well. i want to say, the pnl is calculate only when one round trade happen, one round means one buy and one sell, only calculate in the last one, the first one dont have pnl, because it is a unfinished status

Comment: Only my opinion, but you have an iterative algorithm, and hard if only possible to *vectorize*. Pandas or numpy are great and efficient tools provided you can *broadcast* processing on multiple rows at the same time. Here I would not even try to use pandas, and would not expect numpy to provide a high gain. The algorithm is iterative, so process it iteratively. And if the execution time is not acceptable, use Cython or Numba to process the low level details at C speed. But only posted as a comment because it contains only opinions and no fact (except for my own experiments on close use cases).

Comment: A signal of 0 means?

Comment: @Paddy3118 no action(buy or sell), just wait.

Comment: (In your secon d signal list you buy twice then try and sell three times)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a Python generator function. If you arrange for both the price and signal to be generators themselves then it will generate results at every signal without having to consume memory saving all of the inputs, or outputs - you can stream data through the function.

```
In [31]: def trade(price, signal):
    ...:     n, t, result = 0, 0, []
    ...:     for p, s in zip(price, signal):
    ...:         if s == 1:
    ...:             n, t = n+1, t+p
    ...:             yield 0
    ...:         elif s== 0:
    ...:             yield 0
    ...:         elif s == -1:
    ...:             avg = t/n
    ...:             n, t = n-1, t-avg
    ...:             yield p - avg
    ...:         else:
    ...:             assert s in (1, 0, -1), f"Signal {s} error"

In [32]: price = [100, 99, 98, 99, 101, 102]
    ...: signal= [1,   -1,  1,  1,  -1,   0]

In [33]: list(trade(price, signal))
Out[33]: [0, -1.0, 0, 0, 2.5, 0]

In [34]:
```